# Где хранится информация о потоках?

Tags: c++, многопоточность, ос

Когда я создаю объект потока std::thread, я получаю поток в ядре? Имеется ввиду что ядро будет знать о потоке и если например из потока сделаю вызов yield, то мы перейдем в kernel space

Comment: https://habr.com/post/40227/

Comment: Конечно, поток в С++ - это обычно обертка над системным API для работы с потоками. Для получения системного дескриптора даже предусмотрен специальный метод `std::thread::native_handle`